"Publishing geom data from MySQL 8 in GeoServer with latitude values outside the (-90, 90) range."
When I publish geometry data in mysql8 using geoserver 2.26.0, the order of latitude and longitude is (latitude, longitude) instead of (longitude，latitude ). The reason is that when mysql8 stores geographic data, the longitude and latitude are stored in the (latitude, longitude) order. As a result, the geoserver identifies the range.x identifies the range of mysql mid-latitudes.y identifies the range of longitudes. This occurs after srid is added when mysql inserts wkt data. Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem? How is it solved? Can you help me.
If you do not add srid when inserting geometry data, the longitude and latitude sequence of the geometry data is the same as that of the inserted data by default. If I use update mytable set geom = ST_setsrid(geom, 4326) where st_srid(geom) = 0; The storage sequence of geometry data in mysql8 is changed to (latitude,longitude).
